# Getting Missing Months

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am working on a project where I am trying to chart the number of monthly order that I have received. My current data for monthlyOrder is:

```
[
  {
    _id: { month: 12, year: 2021 },
    year: 2021,
    month: 'December',
    orders: 1
  },
  {
    _id: { month: 4, year: 2022 },
    year: 2022,
    month: 'April',
    orders: 31
  },
  {
    _id: { month: 5, year: 2022 },
    year: 2022,
    month: 'May',
    orders: 2
  }
]
```

I would like to have an array with all missing months with `orders: 0`, so that all months since the first month/date are included in the chart.

I have attempted to do this by:

```
let startYear = monthlyOrders[0]._id.year;
        let startMonth = monthlyOrders[0]._id.month;
        let endYear = monthlyOrders[monthlyOrders.length - 1]._id.year;
        let endMonth = monthlyOrders[monthlyOrders.length - 1]._id.month;
        let months = [
            'January',
            'February',
            'March',
            'April',
            'May',
            'June',
            'July',
            'August',
            'September',
            'October',
            'November',
            'December',
        ];

function getMonthlys () {
    if (startYear === endYear) {
      if (startMonth === endMonth) {
       let date = {
           month: startMonth,
           year: startYear,
       }
       if (startMonth < endMonth) {
          let months = 1;
             while (months <= endMonth) {
              months = months + 1;
              }
           let date = 
           {
               month: months,
               year: startYear,
           }
       }
    }
    }
}
```

However, this is probably not the best way to do this, and I am not sure how to deal with dates where `startYear < endYear`, but `startMonth === endMonth`.

Additionally, to deal with adding 0 for orders when one doesn't exist I have tried to do this:

```
 let monthsObj = [];
        for (let i = startYear; i <= endYear; i++) {
            for (let j = startMonth; j <= 12; j++) {
                if (!(j > endMonth && i === endYear)) {
                    let obj = {
                        month: j,
                        year: i,
                    };
                    monthsObj.push(obj);
                }
            }
        }

        
        for (let dateVal of monthsObj) {
            let isInArray = false;

            for (let dayVal of monthlyOrders) {
                

                if (dayVal._id.year == dateVal.year && dayVal._id.month == dateVal.month) {
                    isInArray = true;
                }
            }
            if (isInArray === false) {
                let obj = {
                    month: dateVal.month,
                    year: dateVal.year,
                };
                monthlyOrders.push({ _id: obj, year: dateVal.year, month: months[dateVal.month - 1], orders: 0 });
               
            }
        }
```

I would really appreciate any suggestion or on how to get the:

```
[
  {
    _id: { month: 12, year: 2021 },
    year: 2021,
    month: 'December',
    orders: 1
  },
 {
    _id: { month: 1, year: 2022 },
    year: 2022,
    month: 'January',
    orders: 0
  },
 {
    _id: { month: 2, year: 2022 },
    year: 2022,
    month: 'February',
    orders: 0
  },
{
    _id: { month: 3, year: 2022 },
    year: 2022,
    month: 'March',
    orders: 0
  },

  {
    _id: { month: 4, year: 2022 },
    year: 2022,
    month: 'April',
    orders: 31
  },
  {
    _id: { month: 5, year: 2022 },
    year: 2022,
    month: 'May',
    orders: 2
  }
]
```

array that I need.

Comment: use the javascript `Date` object. You can compare them, add 1 month, etc.

Comment: are we safe to assume that the dates in the original array of objects are sorted by date?

Comment: @OctaviaSima HI, Yes, I believe so. They're coming from a mongodb database that I aggregated and sorted by month and year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, this is probably not the best way to do this, and I am not sure how to deal with dates where startYear < endYear, but startMonth === endMonth.

I think an easier approach would be for each iteration of the loop to add a *single object* to the output array, along with keeping track of the current index of the input array being iterated over. If, on an iteration, the object in the input array has a matching month and year, push it - otherwise, push the placeholder object (with the one-indexed month accounted for). Then, if index being iterated over is the final one in the original array, break - otherwise, increment the month and then (if needed) the year.

```js
const monthlyOrders=[{_id:{month:12,year:2021},year:2021,month:"December",orders:1},{_id:{month:4,year:2022},year:2022,month:"April",orders:31},{_id:{month:5,year:2022},year:2022,month:"May",orders:2}];
const months=["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"];

let { year, month } = monthlyOrders[0]._id;
const endYear = monthlyOrders[monthlyOrders.length - 1]._id.year;
const endMonth = monthlyOrders[monthlyOrders.length - 1]._id.month;

const output = [];
let monthlyOrdersIndex = 0;
while (monthlyOrdersIndex !== monthlyOrders.length) {
    // If the month/year we're on exists in the original array, use it:
    if (year === monthlyOrders[monthlyOrdersIndex]._id.year && month === monthlyOrders[monthlyOrdersIndex]._id.month) {
        output.push(monthlyOrders[monthlyOrdersIndex]);
        monthlyOrdersIndex++;
    } else {
        output.push({
            _id: { month, year },
            year: year,
            month: months[month - 1],
            orders: 0
        });
    }
    month = month === 12 ? 1 : month + 1;
    if (month === 1) year++;
}
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Thank you! This is a lot less convoluted and makes a ton more sense than how I was thinking to go about it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the javascript Date object to compare an step through the months. Your code, I couldn't tell what it was doing with each month, but this adds them to an array and returns it.

```
let startYear = 2021;
        let startMonth = 6;
        let endYear = 2023;
        let endMonth = 2;
        let months = [
            'January',
            'February',
            'March',
            'April',
            'May',
            'June',
            'July',
            'August',
            'September',
            'October',
            'November',
            'December',
        ];

function getMonthlys () {
  var list = []
  var startdate = new Date(startYear, startMonth, 1)
  var enddate = new Date(endYear, endMonth, 1)
  while (startdate < enddate) {
    list.push({
        month: startdate.getMonth(),
      year: startdate.getFullYear()
    })
    startdate.setMonth(startdate.getMonth() + 1) 
  }
  return list
}

var allmonths = getMonthlys();
```

Then you just need to find the data for each one of those months

```
// for each month, find a match
var orders = allmonths.map( function(month) {

   var match = datasrc.find(function(entry) {
        return entry._id.month == month.month && entry._id.year == month.year
   });
   if (match) {
     return match
   }
   else {
     return {
       _id: month,
       month: months[month.month-1],
       year: month.year,
       orders: 0
     }
   }

})
```

You can see in this fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/myt19j30/1/